# Variable in for loop in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here is my batch file :

```
    @echo off

    cd "D:/myFiles"

    for /r %%filename in (*) do (

    set f=%%filename

    echo %f%

    )

    pause
```

What I m expecting is,it will list all the files in myFiles directory.

But what I am getting is 'Echo is Off' for the same number of times as the number of files in directory 'myFiles'.

With

```
    echo %%filename
```

I can list filename but I have to do some more operation on filename and so to have to store it in a variable like as currently its stored in variable f.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Search for `delayed expansion` as this is a question that is asked regularly.

Answer (score 1):

You need setlocal enabledelayedexpansion to allow the re-evaluation of the variable you set inside the loop. variable expansion needs the `!var!` usage, rather than `%var%`. e.g.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /r   %%f in (*) do (
    set n=%%f
    echo !n!
)
```

Comment: But if I want to manipulate the variable n,then how it can be accomplished ?

Comment: Quite easily - but first you need to send everyone a crystal ball so that we can read your mind. Tell us how you want to manipulate the name, and we may be able to help.